# How to copy XAML designer image

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

Does anyone know how I can copy a rendered image that is displayed in VS2012's XAML Designer?

For example, I want to copy a rendered image from the Designer to a Word document. How do I do it? Ctrl-C doesn't seem to work.

Comment: use the snipping tool http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-capture-screen-shots#1TC=windows-8

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: use Ctrl and PrintScreen and paste it to your Paint. No other apps needed BTW Ctrl + PrintScreen will only take the active window and nothing else.